# File Can Not Be Moved. ERROR: File not moved correctly from to ../productimage/Large/

Tags: php

```
$fileName = $_FILES["product-image"]["name"]; 
$pathAndName = "../productimage/Large/".$fileName;
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["product-image"]["tmp_name"] , $pathAndName);

if ($moveResult) {
  echo "File has been moved from " . $_FILES["product-image"]["tmp_name"] . " to " . $pathAndName;
  exit();
} else {
  echo "ERROR: File not moved correctly from" . $_FILES["product-image"]["tmp_name"] . " to " . $pathAndName;
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the destination folder(../productimage/Large/) has correct write permissions (777) ?

I am afraid that the destination folder hasn't correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
$fileName = $_FILES["product-image"]["name"];
$pathName = "../productimage/Large/";
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileName , $pathName/$fileName);
if(is_writable($pathName)){ ///// verify directory chmod 777
if ($moveResult) { 
echo "File has been moved from " . $fileName . " to " . $pathName; exit();
 }else { 
 echo "ERROR: File not moved correctly from" . $fileName . " to " . $pathName; exit(); 
 }
}else{
exit("Failed to write to directory $save_directory");
}
```